# When should I create my enterprise?

Tags: company

I'm a young french developer (developing for about one-two years). I'm working at a big company but I don't really feel happy to enrich a society that is not mine (although I put a lot of myself into it because I always put a lot in what I do).

My goal has always been to create my own enterprise (create an application or something like that) and I always felt that the good moment to do that was when I'll feel really comfortable (When? I'm a really quick learner and I already think I can maybe handle a project and whatever if I don't know how to do something? I still can learn on the job.) and when I'll learn nothing more. But problem is, I think we always learn on that domain.

I already work for myself when I'm not at my work but I don't have so much time and after 8 hours of developping at my job I feel tired so I'm really frustrated of not having more time or when my brain needs a break (my brain isn't a machine). And of course I want to live and have others activities sometimes. I know: 'You must settle your own path in life'.

My question may be stupid but I really would like you to give me your thoughts on it:

When should I create my enterprise? When is the good moment to do that?

Comment: Do you have an idea? Do you know anyone interested in partnering with you? Do you have sufficient funds to drop out for a year and work on your idea to a point where you can get investors interested? Or are you able to work in the evenings?

Comment: Could those who have downvoted explain why ?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a forum but a Q&A site with guidelines on what kind of questions we can answer here. Check the [help] for more. Asking for advice specific to your situation or on a specific career path is off-topic here. You could try asking the people in [chat] for feedback once  you have 20 reputation on the site.

Answer (score 3):

I think you underestimate the amount of time and energy it takes to launch a startup.

The advantage to being a worker-bee is that when your work day is done, it's really done (or at least it can be).  Entrepeneurs (especially in the startup phase) simply do not have this luxury and it can be very hard to find balance while developing a successful business.  For most this is not a "bad" thing as the venture is exciting and they really get off on developing it, so working *is* life, and enjoyable at that.

Based on that, though, I have to say that if you are exhausted after 8 hours of working (no judgement, I am too!), you value having a good work/life balance, you want to have time for activities other than work, etc.  I think you might want to reconsider this venture of yours.

But to answer your question:  a "right" time might be after you've spent some time working the extra hours to develop your venture while continuing to work in your current position.  This is an excellent test for determining whether this project is exciting enough to you that you can keep your motivation AND put in long hours working.  If you find those longer hours working comfortable, or even motivating, and you can remain committed to the project in spite of any discomfort, it is a good sign that you might be ready to throw everything into your venture.

Comment: I don't underestimate the amout of time and enrgy it takes. I'm awake of that. As I said I'm already working for myself. Thank you for all your answers and @Draken for edit. Seeing the -4 I'll delete my post, I guess my question is too bad or too stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are very exceptional at your job, and/or your father is a politician and can get you very a string of very good customers, I would say it is still to early to leave the workforce.

What some people that have stomach for a world of politics do, is working, usually later on life, as a public servant, leaving early and working on the side for their  own in the remaining of the day for a risk-free life.

I would advise to have at least between 5 or 10 years of work experience to launch your own consulting gig.

As for your potentially killer app, nothing prevents you starting working on it.

[cynic mode on] Start getting on politics/and or religion now for establishing a network of future customers.

Answer (score 0):

@user82047's answer covers the main points:
Starting an entreprise is hard and a lot of work, if you're not sure about yourself don't start now.

However, I'd like to point out that a point specific to IT (I'm assuming developper in your case is computer developement): Writting code requires a minimal amount of ressource.

As such the need for starting a company before working on your project is little. As you suggested it is very simple to work on side projects, and if you're very enthusiastic about them, make them take gradually more space and time in your life.

It isn't necessary to quit your job to start working on your own thing. Take your time and be 100% certain that you're ready to invest your entire life for several years before starting your company.